# Actualizar datos en Masa MySQL

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente necesito actualizar los datos de una tabla de forma masiva es decir tengo una tabla llamada "ordenes" y necesito actualizar los siguientes campos:
`id` ,  `vtex_created_at` ,  `created_at` ,  `updated_at`
como son muchos no puedo ir uno por uno actualizando por eso deseo saber si hay alguna forma para actualizar todo en masa les agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: Pero sera con base a alguna condición si no solo haces el UPDATE y se actualizara todo

Comment: la cosa es que son bastantes registros que tengo que actualizar por eso queria ver alguna forma para hacerlo masivamente

Comment: y cual seria la condicion para actualizar? es decir `where campo = `

Comment: En resumen, puedes hacer un `update ordenes set vtex_created_at = 'MiNuevoValor', created_at = 'OtroValor' where CampoCondicion= 'Valor'`.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer una tabla intermedia para cargar los datos, y hacer el update de la tabla T1

```
UPDATE T1, T2,
T1 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
SET T1.ID = T2.NuevoID, 
    T1.vtext_created_at = T2.vtext_created_at
```